# Auto Downloaded Emails Marked As Read in Inbox

Tags: mac, mail.app, email

I open up my mac mail and I have a ton of emails downloaded which are marked as read even though I have not clicked on them or viewed them. This started to happen within the last month.

I have missed some really important email because they were marked as read. How do I fix this so that all emails stay UNread until I get to them?

Answer (score 1):

This can occur with some providers if you have another device that receives the E-Mails via IMAP.

Make sure all devices that access the account use IMAP or all use POP.